# cakephp: HELP: cron_dispatcher 1.3 failes on import plugin models

Tags: cakephp-1.3

I can't seem to import a plugin model when running controller from the
cron_dispatcher.  Here is a simple test result.

ver: 1.3.2
cron_dispatcher: http://tricks.cakephp.in.th/comland-line-and-cronjob

1. running from web ......... [WORKS]
2. running testA function WITHOUT model import from cmd line.........
   [WORKS]
3. running testB function WITH model import from cmd line.........
   [FAILED] - No errors given

### code:

class CronsController extends PluginAppController {

```
    var $uses = array();

    function testA()
    {
            echo 'Working';
            die;
    }

    function testB()
    {
            App::import('Model', 'Plugin.Report');
            $report = new Report();

            echo 'Working';
            die;
    }
```

Comment: Does testB work on the web too?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cron Dispatcher CakePHP 2.0](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23636079/761202)

Answer (score 1):

Hmmmm. I wonder if a shell would work better? (http://www.utoxin.name/2009/07/cakephp-shells-and-cron-jobs/)

Comment: hi,

thanks for getting back to me.  As usual the issue was my doing.  I had some custom code in the database.php file that was the problem.

-trav