# Cron Dispatcher Error - CakePHP 2.0

Tags: cakephp, cron, cakephp-2.0

Following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8722519/836343) I am having some issues getting my cron to run.

I set it up as outlined at the attached post but my cron when running I get this error:

```
Status: 302 Found
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.8
Set-Cookie: CAKEPHP=7ae47e0238594f2b9b93d2e9017ddd63; expires=Mon, 05-Nov-2012 21:00:07 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly
Location: https:// /tasks/cron_emailer
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

My cron path is as follows: 
**php /home/village/public_html/app/webroot/cron_dispatcher.php /tasks/cron_emailer**

Any idea where I am going wrong? It seems like it is a path issue to me going from the location in the error.

Comment: Is there a reason you're doing it this way instead of using Cake's already existing CLI environment?

Comment: I couldn't work out how to go about using CLI. The documentation was confusing to me. Thsnks

Comment: How would I go about processing /tasks/cron_emailer using CLI and a cron? Thanks

Comment: Well, it's easy if you have the Cake CLI working. If you don't, I suggest you try and get it working first (the docs are pretty good on this). Take a look at [Creating a Shell](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells.html#creating-a-shell) for a quick guide. Then you would just simple set a cron job to call that shell :) It would look something like `cake -app /path/to/app myShell myCommand`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cron Dispatcher CakePHP 2.0](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23636079/761202)