# Undefined variable: argc [APP/webroot/cron_dispatcher.php, line <b>87</b>]<

Tags: php, cakephp-1.3

I am running a cron job using the cron_dispatcher.php file. But I'm getting the following error message:

```
Undefined variable: argc [APP/webroot/cron_dispatcher.php, line 87]
```

My Code at Line 87 is

```php
define('CRON_DISPATCHER', true);
if ($argc == 2) {
    $Dispatcher = new Dispatcher();
    $Dispatcher -> dispatch($argv[1]);
```

My cron command is
    /web/cgi-bin/php5 /my/path/to/html/app/webroot/cron_dispatcher.php /users/test/

Thank you.

EDIT
**Solved:**.
Solution is run cron command in CLI mode
    /usr/local/php5/bin/php  (Godaddy Server Specific).

It will show error but ultimatly run the controller's action.

Thanks for every one especially "VSTM".

Comment: Can you check if [`register_argc_argv`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.register-argc-argv) is set to "1" in your php.ini? If it is, are you sure you're calling the script with the PHP-CLI and not with PHP-CGI? (adding the cron-line to your question might help us)

Comment: I have included cron line now.

Comment: Thanks vstm I got a way to solve it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cron Dispatcher CakePHP 2.0](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23636079/761202) (although it's a different version of CakePHP - the answer is the same).

Answer (score 1):

The variables `$argc` and `$argv` only exist if the relevant php.ini directive is enabled.

You should instead use `$_SERVER['argc']` and `$_SERVER['argv']`.