# Cronjob in CakePHP 1.3

Tags: cakephp, cron

I need a cron job in one of my older web site (CakePHP 1.3).
I made the following steps:

1. created shell in `/somepath/public_html/app/vendors/shells/valute.php`

   ```
   class ValuteShell extends Shell {
       var $uses = array('Valute');
       function main() {
           $this->Valute->cacheGetKonverterData();
       }
   }
   ```
2. created BASH script and save this to my vendors folder as `cakeshell` `(/somepath/public_html/app/vendors/cakeshell)`

   > ```
   > #!/bin/bash
   > TERM=dumb
   > export TERM
   > cmd="cake"
   > while [ $# -ne 0 ]; do
   >     if [ "$1" = "-cli" ] || [ "$1" = "-console" ]; then
   >         PATH=$PATH:$2
   >         shift
   >     else
   >         cmd="${cmd} $1"
   >     fi
   >     shift
   > done
   > $cmd
   > ```
3. changed the permissions on the this file to 777.
4. called cronjob like this:

   ```
   0  0   *   *   *   /somepath/public_html/app/vendors/cakeshell valute -cli /usr/bin -console /somepath/public_html/cake/console -app /somepath/public_html/app
   ```

Unfortunately cronjob does not work. Why?
When I call: http://www.somedomain.net/valutes/save_valute 
everything works fine.

```
<?php
class ValutesController extends AppController {
    var $name = 'Valutes';
    var $uses = array('Valute'); 

    function save_valutes()
    {
        $this->layout = null; // turn off the layout    
        $this->Valute->cacheGetKonverterData();
    }   
}
?>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cron Dispatcher CakePHP 2.0](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23636079/761202) (while this question uses a custom bash script - the right solution is to just call Console/cake ).

Answer (score 0):

`cakeshell`: `cmd` should have the PATH of the Cake core's `cake` file

```
cmd="/somepath/public_html/lib/Cake/Console/cake"
```

`crontab`:

```
0 0 * * * /somepath/public_html/app/vendors/cakeshell valute -app /somepath/public_html/app >> var/log/crontab
```

Comment: thank you for your reply, but unfortunately that's not working

Comment: I did not notice the error. I solved the problem in another way:  curl -sfo /dev/null www.somedomain.com/controller/action/secret_code. This is the sort of improvisation, but it works.