# Cakephp Console/cake not working for Cron Job

Tags: cakephp, ssh, cron, cpanel

This is part of troubleshooting why my Cron job set up via CPanel to run a Cakephp shell, isn't working.

This is what I initially did, after reading http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells.html
I created via CPanel cronjob that runs every 1 minute the following command:

```
php /home4/theadvop/public_html/app/Console/Cake test
```

By right I'm expecting it to execute TestShell.php (stored in Console/Command). This TestShell.php is a class that extends Appshell, and has a main() function that sends a test email in php code.

All of the above didn't work, no emails were sent, and no error logs were produced anywhere. So i decided to manually test things via SSH as shown below, which also strangely, shows no output.

Via SSH I've browsed to my app directory and tried running Console/cake, I get permission error. 
So I did  a chmod as shown in the attachment.
[image]

Now I tried running Console/cake from the app folder. But no output and nothing happens. Eventually I have to Ctrl-C my way out of it.
[image]

I then try to run Console/cake using my php file as a parameter (my php file is called TestShell.php in the Console/Command folder. Again nothing happens.
[image]

Any idea whats wrong with my setup?

Edited below to include email output.

Note I have changed my Console/Command/TestShell.php to output a line simply like this. It no longer attempts to send an email (to keep things simple)

```
echo "This is an output from testshell";
```

My Cron Job when running this:

```
php /home4/theadvop/public_html/app/Console/Cake test
```

Will result in the Cron sending me email that looks like this:

```
Content-type: text/html

################################################################################
#
# Bake is a shell script for running CakePHP bake script
#
# CakePHP(tm) :  Rapid Development Framework (http://cakephp.org)
# Copyright (c) Cake Software Foundation, Inc. (http://cakefoundation.org)
#
# Licensed under The MIT License
# For full copyright and license information, please see the LICENSE.txt
# Redistributions of files must retain the above copyright notice.
#
# @copyright     Copyright (c) Cake Software Foundation, Inc. (http://cakefoundation.org)
# @link          http://cakephp.org CakePHP(tm) Project
# @package       app.Console
# @since         CakePHP(tm) v 1.2.0.5012
# @license       http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php MIT License
#
################################################################################

# Canonicalize by following every symlink of the given name recursively
canonicalize() {
        NAME="$1"
        if [ -f "$NAME" ]
        then
                DIR=$(dirname -- "$NAME")
                NAME=$(cd -P "$DIR" && pwd -P)/$(basename -- "$NAME")
        fi
        while [ -h "$NAME" ]; do
                DIR=$(dirname -- "$NAME")
                SYM=$(readlink "$NAME")
                NAME=$(cd "$DIR" && cd $(dirname -- "$SYM") && pwd)/$(basename -- "$SYM")
        done
        echo "$NAME"
}

CONSOLE=$(dirname -- "$(canonicalize "$0")")
APP=$(dirname "$CONSOLE")

exec php -q "$CONSOLE"/cake.php -working "$APP" "$@"
exit
```

Did not understand the above but i think Cron was executing the wrong thing because the output seemed to be about "baking".

After that I tried to remove the "php" of the cron job command so the cron runs this:

```
/home4/theadvop/public_html/app/Console/Cake test
```

The Cron then sends me the following email:

```
/home4/theadvop/public_html/app/Console/cake: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
/home4/theadvop/public_html/app/Console/cake: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
/home4/theadvop/public_html/app/Console/cake: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
/home4/theadvop/public_html/app/Console/cake: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
/home4/theadvop/public_html/app/Console/cake: fork: Resource temporarily unavailable
No input file specified.
```

I still have no idea what i'm doing wrong.

Comment: did you set email id for getting cron result in your email box. It will send you the error of cron

Comment: Yes I did and I get emails with the following content.  Not sure wgat to make of it...

Comment: is it showing any error in your email?

Comment: Ill update my post in 20 mins and show the email

Comment: I've added the 2 different emails that Cron sends to me when running with and without the "php" at the start of the cron command.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I just dealt with a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this method for setting cron in cakephp

Write your code in a controller's action.
Then check for cron_dispatcher.php in webroot folder.
In there is no such file download it from internet. Google for it you will find easily. Or check this link [Cron Dispatcher CakePHP 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8485533/cron-dispatcher-cakephp-2-0)
And then set below path in cpanel :-

```
  php /home4/theadvop/public_html/app/webroot/cron_dispatcher.php /controller/action
```

Remind that put a die() in the end of your code otherwise it will give error for a ctp file. Or put a blank ctp file for that function.

Hope it will help

Comment: hi, unless ill try your method only if i really run out of possible solutions for doing it the proper cake way. From what i understand there shuldn't be a need to use the dispatcher for this

Comment: replace php with cd in your cronjob command. Check http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells/cron-jobs.html

Answer (score 0):

create a file in webroot folder of cake php. The file contains all the cron url with their timings like this :-

```
 * 10 * * * /usr/bin/curl http://cronurl/
```

Now execute this command

```
 crontab /path/to/file
```

your cron job will be added.
You can also list all cron jobs under every user through the following command.

```
for user in $(cut -f1 -d: /etc/passwd); do crontab -u $user -l; done
```

Answer (score 0):

Add extention `.php` after `/cake`

```
php bin/cake.php server...
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the top of cron

```
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
```